# First Python program: Tic-Tac-Toe (Followup)

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I am unsure if I followed the the suggestions on my [previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/217235/first-python-program-tic-tac-toe/217290).
I have only been working on programming for about 3 weeks so any more suggestions or insight would be more than welcomed.

```
import sys
from textwrap import dedent
import os
import random

os.system('CLS')

# board number setup
board = [0, 1, 2,
         3, 4, 5,
         6, 7, 8]


# Defines the board layout printed to the console
def board_layout():
    print(dedent(f''' 
    *************
    * {board[0]} | {board[1]} | {board[2]} *
    *-----------*
    * {board[3]} | {board[4]} | {board[5]} *
    *-----------*
    * {board[6]} | {board[7]} | {board[8]} *
    *************
    '''))


def main():
    players = ('Player','NPC')
    turn = 'Player'
    change_turn = 0
    for moves in range(9):
        if turn == 'Player':   
            while True:
                try:
                    board_layout()
                    player_move = int(input('Please select a spot: '))
                    if board[player_move] != 'x' and board[player_move] != 'o':
                        board[player_move] = 'x'
                        check_winner()
                        break
                except IndexError:
                    print('please select valid spot')
        if turn == 'NPC':
             # npc move, chooses a random spot that is not taken 
            while True:
                npc = random.randint(0, 8)
                if board[npc] != 'o' and board[npc] != 'x':
                    board[npc] = 'o'
                    print('Computer chooses spot ', npc)
                    check_winner()
                    break  
        try:
            change_turn += 1
            turn = players[change_turn]
        except:
            change_turn = 0
            turn = players[change_turn]
    else:
       print('You Tied')
       end()       





def end():
        print('Thank you for playing')
        answer = input('Would you like to play again?: Y/N')

        if answer.lower() == 'n':
            quit()
        elif answer.lower() == 'y':
                    clear_board()
                    main()
        else:
            print('Please choose a valid option')
            end()

def clear_board():
    for i in range(9):
        board[i] = i

# checks for a winner when called at end of each turn        
def check_winner():

            # list of lists with all the winning combinations for from the tic tac toe board
            winning_list = [[board[0], board[1], board[2]], [board[3], board[4], board[5], ],
                            [board[6], board[7], board[8]], [board[0], board[4], board[8]],
                            [board[2], board[4], board[6]],
                            [board[0], board[3], board[6]], [board[1], board[4], board[7]],
                            [board[2], board[5], board[8]]]

            # iterates over the lists in winning_list
            for i, j, k in winning_list:
                # looks at the lists in winning_list to determine if a list has all x's for a win
                if i == 'x' and j == 'x' and k == 'x':
                    print('X wins')
                    end()
                # looks at the lists in winning_list to determine if a list has all o's for a win
                elif i == 'o' and j == 'o' and k == 'o':
                    print('O wins')
                    end()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Many of your code improvements can be taken from this post, please have a look: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201506/tictactoe-game-in-python-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You now have two methods of setting up the board.  The first is direct initialization:

```
board = [0, 1, 2,
         3, 4, 5,
         6, 7, 8]
```

and the second is a resetting an already existing board:

```
def clear_board():
    for i in range(9):
        board[i] = i
```

I hate that there are two.  It would be easy to make a mistake and change one (for example, changing to a 4x4 grid) but not the other.

---

`board_layout()` is an odd name for the function that prints the board.  It is not laying out the board.  I might call it `print_board()`.

I dislike seeing the same thing over and over.  In `board_layout()`, you have `board[ ]` appear 9 times in the format string.  If you wanted to change the name of the game board, you'd have to edit the code in 9 places in this one function.  You can eliminate these duplicates using the `.format()` command, instead of using a f-string.  I know, seems like going backwards; f-strings are supposed to be an improvement!

```
''' 
*************
* {} | {} | {} *
*-----------*
* {} | {} | {} *
*-----------*
* {} | {} | {} *
*************
'''.format(*board)
```

`*board` takes the `board` list, takes the individual elements and "splats" them all as the arguments to the `.format()` call.  Each argument, in turn, is substituted into the next `{}` format code.

---

Jumping ahead.

```
        winning_list = [[board[0], board[1], board[2]], [board[3], board[4], board[5], ],
                        [board[6], board[7], board[8]], [board[0], board[4], board[8]],
                        [board[2], board[4], board[6]],
                        [board[0], board[3], board[6]], [board[1], board[4], board[7]],
                        [board[2], board[5], board[8]]]
```

Again, here we have `board[ ]` repeated 24 times!  There has got to be a better way.  And there is.  First, create as a global constant, a list of list of winning indices.  Since these will never be modified, I've used tuples instead of lists.

```
WINNING_ROWS = ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8),  # Rows
                (0, 3, 6), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8),  # Columns
                (0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6))             # Diagonals
```

Now we just need to use these indices to check for a win condition.  We can even use chained comparisons to make the test more concise:

```
    for i, j, k in WINNING_ROWS:
        if board[i] == board[j] == board[k] == 'x':
            print('X wins')
```

That tests `board[i] == board[j]` AND `board[j] == board[k]` AND `board[k] == 'x'`, but we haven't repeated any of the terms in the test.

```
        elif board[i] == board[j] == board[k] == 'o':
            print('O wins')
```

And now we have.

Whenever you repeat code, you should think "maybe a loop" or "maybe a function".  A loop doesn't seem right here.  Let's use a function:

```
def has_won(player):
    for i, j, k in WINNING_ROWS:
        if board[i] == board[j] == board[k] == player:
            return True
    return False
```

Now you can use `if has_won('x'):` to check in the `'x'` player has won after they have made their move, and `if has_won('o'):` to check if the `'o'` player has won after they have made theirs.

We can condense this function.  The `all()` function will test each of its arguments, and return `True` only if all of the arguments are true.  We can use list comprehension to extract each index in turn from the row tuples:

```
def has_won(player):
    for row in WINNING_ROWS:
        if all(board[idx] == player for idx in row):
            return True
    return False
```

Like the `all()` function, there is an `any()` function, which returns `True` if any of its arguments are true.  Again, we'll use list comprehension to loop over each row in `WINNING_ROWS`:

```
def has_won(player):
    return any(all(board[idx] == player for idx in row) for row in WINNING_ROWS)
```

For any of the winning rows, if all of the board locations contain the player's symbol, `True` is returned.  Pretty darn concise, if you want to use it.

---

Checking for a valid spot:

```
if board[player_move] != 'x' and board[player_move] != 'o':

if board[npc] != 'o' and board[npc] != 'x':
```

Effectively the same test, repeated twice.  And `board[pos]` referenced twice in each test.  Don't Repeat Yourself.  DRY.  As opposed to Write Everything Twice, or WET.  You want DRY code, not WET code.  The `in` operator will test if the item on the left of `in` is contained in the container on the right.

```
def is_valid_move(move):
    return board[move] not in ('x', 'o')
```

Not bad.  But is `12` a valid move?  How about `-1`?  Note that `-1` will not cause an `IndexError`, it will just return the last element of the list (`board[8]`).

```
def is_valid_move(move):
    return move in range(9) and board[move] not in ('x', 'o')
```

---

Elephant in the room.

You play the game, win, play again, loose, play again, tie, play again.  What is the stack trace at this point?

```
main() -> check_winner() -> end() -> main() -> check_winner() -> end() -> main() -> check_winner() -> end() -> main() -> check_winner() -> end() ...
```

If you make a mistake and enter invalid input in the `end()` method, you could even have `end() -> end()` repeats in that stack trace.

Do not use recursion as a substitute for looping!

---

Here is a possible implementation, which doesn't use recursion.  Note that there are no global variables, other than the constant `WINNING_ROWS`.  Since `board` is no longer global, it can be created brand new each time a game is started.

```
import random

WINNING_ROWS = ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8),
                (0, 3, 6), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8),
                (0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6))

def print_board(board):
    row  = "  {} | {} | {}\n"
    line = " ---+---+---\n" 
    print(((row + line) * 2 + row).format(*board))

def has_won(player, board):
    return any(all(board[idx] == player for idx in row) for row in WINNING_ROWS)

def is_valid_move(move, board):
    return move in range(9) and board[move] not in ('x', 'o')

def player_move(board):
    print_board(board)
    while True:
        try:
            move = int(input('Please select as spot: '))
            if is_valid_move(move, board):
                return move
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print('Invalid input.', end='  ')

def npc_move(board):
    while True:
        move = random.randint(0, 8)
        if is_valid_move(move, board):
            return move

def play_game():

    board = list(range(9))
    player = 'x'

    for _ in range(9):
        if player == 'x':
            move = player_move(board)
        else:
            move = npc_move(board)

        board[move] = player

        if has_won(player, board):
            print_board(board)
            print(f"{player.upper()} wins!")
            return

        player = 'o' if player == 'x' else 'x'

    print("Tie game")

def main():
    answer = 'y'

    while answer == 'y':
        play_game()

        answer = ''
        while answer not in ('y', 'n'):
            answer = input('Play again? (Y/N): ').lower()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```